# 100 Spam Registrations Per Day Even With Low NoSpam

Tags: low-no-spam

We installed Low NoSpam recently and already have captcha enabled and in the Low NoSpam documentation it reads like it will delete all spam registrations, but instead they're just sitting in our database waiting to be deleted. Is this the case and we just need to manually delete them? Or should they automatically be purged. Or is something else wrong? At one point before we caught the issue we had over 800,000 registrations on the site that should only have about few hundred at this point.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Low NoSpam is not deleted members. It is just helps to block spammer.

If you want something different - try [VZ Bad Behavior](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-bad-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings in Low NoSpam. Have you set "check member registrations" to "yes"?

Are also the member groups selected that should be checked?

Comment: Yep, we have that turned on.